# Does XChaCha20 exist with similar properties to XSalsa20?

Tags: stream-cipher, chacha, xsalsa20

Does XChaCha20 (built from ChaCha20 just like XSalsa20 is built from Salsa20) exist and have XSalsa20's desirable properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no specification for XChaCha20. But several implementations provide a HChaCha20 function, built the same way as HSalsa20.

XChaCha20 can be built with HChaCha20 + ChaCha20, and the security proof is similar to the one for XSalsa20.

The Libsodium documentation has a section on [HChaCha20](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/key_derivation/index.html#nonce-extension), which includes a code snippet to build XChaCha20 out of it.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-arciszewski-xchacha-03